# What is max number of characters executing from MySQL command line?

Tags: mysql

I need to execute SQL from MySQL command line with option "--execute=statement, -e statement" but I am afraid my SQL statement is too long which does not fit in option.

If my SQL statement exceeds, how can I set max number of characters of "execute" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql statement will only execute after the ; sign so you can wrap the statement to the next line.....there is no limit per se

if the statement is too large save in a file and save it as a .sql the give the path to the file on the console
     mysql -e "source /path-to-backup/backup-file.sql" db_name